# How to convert the result of a query in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am running below query:

```
${points}    Query    select points from table
```

It gives me below result:

```
[(Decimal('357.0000'),)]
```

How to convert above result as float? I would like to compare it to another float value

I've already tried using Convert to... keywords

Thank you all for your help

Comment: If you have gotten that "result" via printing your list, the actual decimal value should be compareable to any float value just fine. You are seeing the classname because printing the value calls __repr__ and that adds the class name to the output ..  If not, you can typecast the value with float()

Comment: I have added an answer below give it a thumbs up if that is satishfactory!!!

Comment: @rasjani when I try to compare them I get the exeption:
`Suspended due to logged failure: Evaluating expression '[(Decimal('357.0000'),)] > [(Decimal('347.0000'),)]' failed: NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined nor importable as module
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution- the return value of the db query is a list of tuples (that's why my value was equal to [(Decimal('357.0000'),)])
all I had to do was take the first element of the tuple - in my case

```
${points[0][0]}
```

When it comes to comparing two values:

```
Should Be True    ${points[0][0]} > ${points2[0][0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to check on equality. Why not to try **Should Be Equal As Numbers** keyword? It will fail in case objects are unequal after converting them to real numbers.

```
Should Be Equal As Numbers    ${points}   ${another_float_value}
```

In case you would like to check whether one of the values greater than or less than another, I guess you can use **Evaluate** or **Should Be True**:

```
Should Be True    '${points}' > '${another_float_value}'
```

If I am not mistaken the example above will help you to check that *points* is greater than *another_float_value*.

Comment: How can it be done in case I want to check if ${points} is less/more than ${another_float_value}?

Comment: @NataliaG try to check "Evaluate" or "Should Be True" keywords then. Both accept an expression that is evaluated in Python. I updated my answer above with examples.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to execute: 
`Should Be True    ${points} > ${another_float_value}`
I get this exeption:
`Suspended due to logged failure: Evaluating expression '[(Decimal('357.0000'),)] > [(Decimal('347.0000'),)]' failed: NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined nor importable as module
`

Comment: @NataliaG that error message is saying that both of your values are List of Tuples with Decimal in it  - That is not a numeric value, you need to do a for loop around that *or* make what ever keyword you are calling return a bit more saner datatype